# Checking Facebook username availability - Python

Tags: python, facebook

I am currently creating an application which includes checking username availability for social networks, one being Facebook. Using python how would I do this? I have already done it for twitter:

```
url = "https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username=" + username
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

return data.get("reason")
```

Comment: Not possible any more via API – Facebook has removed the `username` field with version 2.0.

Comment: How do you suggest I do it? Read page to see if it is a profile and not 404?

Comment: I’d suggest you don’t. Scraping is against Facebook’s ToS. And I don’t see much use in that feature anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Graph API from Facebook, I've tried one very simple solution.
Basically I'm just checking the response for predefined string.

```
import requests
name = input()
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + name
response = requests.get(url)

if (response.text.find("Some of the aliases you requested do not exist") == -1):
    print("Exist!")
else:
    print("Don't exist!")
```